# SharePoint 2013 - Calculated Columns - Created timestamp is 6 hours into the future

Tags: 2013, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to calculate the difference between created date and now() in calculated column in SharePoint 2013 but i have issue with the time zones.

The servers are in Europe (UTC +2) and some of the user are in Singapore (UTC +8)

When i go to the list and check the list item created by the users, the created timestamp is 6 hours into the future(!). So when i calculate the difference between created date and now, i get a negative number.

I don't know where to start troubleshooting this.

Below is some relevant screen shots.

My User information -- language and region

[image]

server time

[image]

The list item where the timestamp is into the future.

[image]

My formula

[image]

The output of the calculations

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Regional Settings of your SharePoint Site?

https://sharepointmaven.com/sharepoint-time-zone/

> Let’s first start with Regional (Administrative
>   setting). It is important to note that the Regional Setting is set for
>   each site separately. If you set the time zone at the top site of the
>   site collection, it would not propagate automatically to sub-sites.
>   Time zone regional setting needs to be set for each site separately.
>
> To change the regional settings for a SharePoint site (you obviously
>   need to be an Admin to accomplish this):
>
> Open the SharePoint site on which you want to change the Time Zone. On
>   the Site Actions menu, choose Site Settings. On the Site Settings
>   page, under Site Administration, choose Regional settings. On the
>   Regional Settings page, select the Time Zone that you want for this
>   site, and then choose the OK button.

[image]

[image]

> So which time would you choose for Regional Setting? Well, the obvious
>   choice would be to choose one where majority of your users are.

Sounds like the Site was created by someone with Singapore time?